# Google Container Engine Clusters in different regions with cloud load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to run a Google Container Engine Cluster in EU and one in the US, and load balancing between the apps they running on this Google Container Engine Clusters?

Comment: Your question is tagged with google-container-engine, so I'm wondering if by GCE pool you mean [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-pools)?

Comment: Sorry about this, i mean a Google Container Engine Cluster in both regions.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266201/cross-region-load-balancing-routing-on-google-container-engine/37280044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancing, TCP Proxy and SSL Proxy support cross-region load balancing. You can point it at multiple different GKE clusters by creating a backend service that forwards traffic to the instance groups for your node pools, and sends traffic on a NodePort for your service.

However it would be preferable to create the LB automatically, like Kubernetes does for an Ingress.  One way to do this is with [Cluster Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/), which has support for [Federated Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-federation/ingress/).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, for Compute Enginen is this clear, but what i mean is the Container Engine. I have updated my question. Sorry about the unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

Try kubemci for some help in getting this setup.  GKE does not currently support or recommend Kubernetes cluster federation.

From their docs:

> kubemci allows users to manage multicluster ingresses without having to enroll all the clusters in a federation first. This relieves them of the overhead of managing a federation control plane in exchange for having to run the kubemci command explicitly each time they want to add or remove a cluster.
>
> Also since kubemci creates GCE resources (backend services, health checks, forwarding rules, etc) itself, it does not have the same problem of ingress controllers in each cluster competing with each other to program similar resources.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress