# GKE - how to connect two clusters to each other

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'am new to the kubernetes and gcp. I have one cluster called `A` where my service is running. In order to run it needs an elasticsearch cluster. I would like to run the elasticsearch in the different GKE cluster so it won't have any impact on my current services. I created another cluster called `B` and now I have an issue I don't know how to make the service from the `A` cluster to connect to the elasticsearch pod from the `B` cluster.

Currently I've found two solutions:

a) make elasticsearch accessible on the public internet - I want to avoid such solution

b) add to the service another container that would authenticate to the `B` cluster and run `kubectl proxy`

None of them seems to be the perfect solution. How to solve such case ? Do you have any tutorials articles or tips how to solve it properly ?

edit:

important notes:

- both clusters belong to the default vpc
- clusters exist I cannot tear them down and recreate reconfigured

Comment: Have a look at these cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664060 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553640. Also, this example could be useful https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-demos/tree/master/gke-to-gke-peering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expose your service with type `LoadBalancer`. This will create an internal load balancer which other GKE cluster can reach.

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) details the steps.

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service) explains the available service option on GKE in detail.

With these option you dont have to expose your service to public internet or destroy your GKE cluster.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to connect to the load balancer not by the ip but by some dns name ?

Comment: I haven't tried myself this but if you put a DNS entry which resolves to Load balancer IP then it should work